# How to insert a table whole array data to a new table using php and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
include("includes/db.php");
 $customer=$_SESSION['customer'];
//cart data
$get_cart_product=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `cart_data` WHERE 
customer_reg_id=".$_SESSION['customer']);

// order_status
$order_status="Pending";
$invoice_no=mt_rand();

    $total_array=[];
    while($row_fetch_cart=mysqli_fetch_array($get_cart_product)){
    $cart_data_id=$row_fetch_cart['cart_data_id'];
    $cart_pro_id=$row_fetch_cart['product_id'];
    $cart_color_id=$row_fetch_cart['color_id'];
    $cart_size_id=$row_fetch_cart['size_id'];
    $cart_product_price=$row_fetch_cart['product_price'];
    $cart_product_qty=$row_fetch_cart['product_qty'];   
    $vendor_id=$row_fetch_cart['user_id'];
    $customer_reg_id=$row_fetch_cart['customer_reg_id'];

     // Fetching product information
    $get_product=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE product_id=$cart_pro_id");
    $row_fetch_products=mysqli_fetch_array($get_product);
    $product_id=$row_fetch_products['product_id'];
    $product_mrp=$row_fetch_products['product_mrp'];


    //  Cart Total payable amount
    $price=$product_mrp;
    $qty=$cart_product_qty;
    $total=$price*$qty;

    $total_array[]= $total;


?>                              
 <?php }?>  

<?php $total_amount=array_sum($total_array); echo $total_amount;?>"
//now I want to insert whole fetch data from cart_data  table to 
 customer_orders below is my code. but I'm able to insert to only last row 
data
//insert orders
$customer_order_insert="INSERT INTO `customer_orders` (`customer_id`, 
`vendor_id`, `product_id`, `invoice_no`, `total_order`, `paid_amount`, 
`order_status`, `order_date`) VALUES ('$customer_reg_id', '$vendor_id', 
'$cart_pro_id', '$invoice_no', '$cart_product_qty', '$product_mrp', 
'pending', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";

 $run_order_insert=mysqli_query($con,$customer_order_insert);

 if($run_order_insert){

   echo"<script>alert('Order  received successfully')</script>";
 }else{
   echo"<script>alert('Oop! Something  wrong')</script>";
 }
```

Firstly I have fetched all data from the `cart_data` table and then calculate a summation for all fetched mrp. and now I'm going to insert whole fetched row data together into the `customer_orders` table but in my case or code, only last row data is possible to insert customer_order table. So, guys please make a suggestion how I can do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should put insert query inside the loop. here only last record will insert. I updated your code, please try it.

```
   include("includes/db.php");
     $customer=$_SESSION['customer'];
    //cart data
    $get_cart_product=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `cart_data` WHERE 
    customer_reg_id=".$_SESSION['customer']);

    // order_status
    $order_status="Pending";
    $invoice_no=mt_rand();
  $run_order_insert=0;

        $total_array=[];
        while($row_fetch_cart=mysqli_fetch_array($get_cart_product)){
        $cart_data_id=$row_fetch_cart['cart_data_id'];
        $cart_pro_id=$row_fetch_cart['product_id'];
        $cart_color_id=$row_fetch_cart['color_id'];
        $cart_size_id=$row_fetch_cart['size_id'];
        $cart_product_price=$row_fetch_cart['product_price'];
        $cart_product_qty=$row_fetch_cart['product_qty'];   
        $vendor_id=$row_fetch_cart['user_id'];
        $customer_reg_id=$row_fetch_cart['customer_reg_id'];

         // Fetching product information
        $get_product=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE product_id=$cart_pro_id");
        $row_fetch_products=mysqli_fetch_array($get_product);
        $product_id=$row_fetch_products['product_id'];
        $product_mrp=$row_fetch_products['product_mrp'];


        //  Cart Total payable amount
        $price=$product_mrp;
        $qty=$cart_product_qty;
        $total=$price*$qty;

        $total_array[]= $total;

       //insert orders
    $customer_order_insert="INSERT INTO `customer_orders` (`customer_id`, 
    `vendor_id`, `product_id`, `invoice_no`, `total_order`, `paid_amount`, 
    `order_status`, `order_date`) VALUES ('$customer_reg_id', '$vendor_id', 
    '$cart_pro_id', '$invoice_no', '$cart_product_qty', '$product_mrp', 
    'pending', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);";

     $run_order_insert=mysqli_query($con,$customer_order_insert);

    ?>                              
     <?php }?>  

    <?php $total_amount=array_sum($total_array); echo $total_amount;?>"
    //now I want to insert whole fetch data from cart_data  table to 
     customer_orders below is my code. but I'm able to insert to only last row 
    data

     if($run_order_insert){

       echo"<script>alert('Order  received successfully')</script>";
     }else{
       echo"<script>alert('Oop! Something  wrong')</script>";
     }
```

Comment: Thanks It's really very helpful for me

Comment: @kaushik,  it's  okay